# Is there a way to monitor the cassandra table column continuosly for particular columns using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-driver

I need to continuosly monitor the cassandra database table for 2 column values and if column1==true and column2== true, I need to perform some operation.

Will Cassandra-driver library has the ability to do the above? or any other library to perform the above?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the cassandra driver doesn't have such ability.

But Cassandra has [triggers](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/triggers.html) feature. Triggers code should be placed to Cassandra nodes and should be one of JVM languages:

> the trigger can be written in any Java (JVM) language and exists outside the database. You place the trigger code in a lib/triggers subdirectory of the Cassandra installation directory, it loads during cluster startup, and exists on every node that participates in a cluster. The trigger defined on a table fires before a requested DML statement occurs, which ensures the atomicity of the transaction.